# Eliminating ROW_NUMBER() for SQL 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, row-number

I have to migrate a sql to work on Microsoft SQL Server 2000. Unfortunately the current sql uses the function ROW_NUMBER() which is not yet supported in this version. Therefore I have to find something similar.

Below my SQL (I used * instead of listing all columns)

```
SELECT [Id], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InstallmentNumber, ID ASC) AS ROWID
FROM [ARAS].[ARAS].[Movement]
```

Comment: What is the rest of the query doing?  Is it using ROWID to iterate?  If so, there could be other ways to handle this.

Comment: Yes. basically it uses the RowId to filter the data. The idea is to sum all previous total values.
A Select in Select with the following column `(SELECT SUM(Total) WHERE RowId <= currentRowId) AS Balance`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a temp table with an identity column to simulate the ROW_NUMBER may be your best bet performance wise:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpRowNum (
    ROWID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ID INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmpRowNum
    (ID)
    SELECT ID
        FROM [ARAS].[ARAS].[Movement]
        ORDER BY InstallmentNumber, ID
```

Comment: But this does not work in a single select like above, does it? I guess there is no way of preventing using a more complex stored procedure.

Comment: Except that since the above example is using a temp table that is unique to the connection/process/spid, nobody else can affect it. You will always get a contiguous stream of values this way.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, but here's a starting-point:

```
SELECT [Id],
  ( SELECT SUM(1)
    FROM [ARAS].[ARAS].[Movement]
    WHERE InstallmentNumber <= OuterMovement.InstallmentNumber
      AND ID <= OuterMovement.ID
  ) AS ‘Row Number’
FROM [ARAS].[ARAS].[Movement] AS OuterMovement
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable table giving the "ROWID" an INT Identity value and inserting the values into that.

You can also do while w/o using the ROWID.  The performance wouldn't be great though...

```
DECLARE @id INT, @SUM INT
SELECT @id = MIN([Id]) FROM [ARAS].[ARAS].[Movement]    


WHILE EXISTS (SELECT [Id] FROM [ARAS].[ARAS].[Movement] WHERE [Id] >= @id)
BEGIN
    ... do something with the ID ..
    SELECT @SUM = SUM(...) FROM [ARAS].[ARAS].[Movement] WHERE [Id] > @id

    SELECT @id = MIN([Id]) FROM [ARAS].[ARAS].[Movement] WHERE [Id] > @id
END
```