# 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, row-number

My query:

```
select 
    row_number() over(partition by line_no order by line_NO) as orce 
from tx_hsa_summ
```

This is my query when ever I use the over function I keep getting this error

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
>   'row_number' is not a recognized function name.

and this is my db version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2000 - 8.00.2305 (Intel X86) May 14 2012 16:24:50 
Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition 
   on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

pls help me resolve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` was only introduced in the 2005 version of the product.

Answer (score 6):

There is no `ROW_NUMBER()` function in SQL Server 2000, it was presented in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: So how to overcome this pro?

Comment: @sentilkumar - You have to use other logic to simulate the ranking, if you search in Google you would find other alternative for it in SQL Server 2000 using temp tables. See [this](http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2000/simulate-row_number-in-sql-2000), and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5705937/722783).